# Installing Creality CR6 SE Community firmware

Tags: firmware, creality-cr-6

I want to know how simple is it to install CR6Community firmware

https://github.com/CR6Community/Marlin/releases

I do not want to make low-level modifications for it.  And also I want to know how simple is it to get back to official firmware?

I want to update because I came to know it has better calibration options and also I'm having issue with Z Axes that does not remember its position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can reformat a (micro)-SD-card on a Windows PC (there are built-in system tools) and copy files to it, then you have enough skills.

Going back to the stock firmware is as easy as copying the files to an SD-card and having it inserted to the printer while it starts up.

After that you have to reflash the display, but this is similar to flashing the printer, as you have to copy files on a micro-SD-card and unscrew the back of the display to get to the card-slot on the back of the display-control-board.